# Error installing browser-sync on Windows 7 64 bit

Tags: node.js, window, npm, node-gyp

I have installed `node-gyp` and Python 2.7 on my system

Now I am able to install `socket.io` (I was not without setup Python 2.7), but I still not be able to install browser sync using `npm install -g browser-sync`

I really have no ideas how to fix the errors, please guide

Thanks

[image]

[image]

[image]

This is my `npm config ls -l`

```
; cli configs
long = true
user-agent = "npm/2.6.1 node/v1.4.3 win32 x64"

; userconfig C:\Users\Admin\.npmrc
python = "c:\\tools\\python2"

; builtin config undefined
prefix = "C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm"

; default values
access = null
always-auth = false
bin-links = true
browser = null
ca = null
cache = "C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm-cache"
cache-lock-retries = 10
cache-lock-stale = 60000
cache-lock-wait = 10000
cache-max = null
cache-min = 10
cafile = undefined
cert = null
color = true
depth = null
description = true
dev = false
editor = "notepad.exe"
engine-strict = false
fetch-retries = 2
fetch-retry-factor = 10
fetch-retry-maxtimeout = 60000
fetch-retry-mintimeout = 10000
force = false
git = "git"
git-tag-version = true
global = false
globalconfig = "C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\etc\\npmrc"
globalignorefile = "C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\etc\\npmignore"
group = 0
heading = "npm"
https-proxy = null
ignore-scripts = false
init-author-email = ""
init-author-name = ""
init-author-url = ""
init-license = "ISC"
init-module = "C:\\Users\\Admin\\.npm-init.js"
init-version = "1.0.0"
json = false
key = null
link = false
local-address = undefined
loglevel = "warn"
; long = false (overridden)
message = "%s"
node-version = "1.4.3"
npat = false
onload-script = null
optional = true
parseable = false
; prefix = "c:\\Program Files\\nodejs" (overridden)
production = false
proprietary-attribs = true
proxy = null
rebuild-bundle = true
registry = "https://registry.npmjs.org/"
rollback = true
save = false
save-bundle = false
save-dev = false
save-exact = false
save-optional = false
save-prefix = "^"
scope = ""
searchexclude = null
searchopts = ""
searchsort = "name"
shell = "C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe"
shrinkwrap = true
sign-git-tag = false
spin = true
strict-ssl = true
tag = "latest"
tmp = "C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp"
umask = 0
unicode = true
unsafe-perm = true
usage = false
user = 0
; user-agent = "npm/{npm-version} node/{node-version} {platform} {arch}" (overridden)
userconfig = "C:\\Users\\Admin\\.npmrc"
version = false
versions = false
viewer = "browser"
```